# How to effectively use pandas to change values based unique identifier and one condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
   identifier loan_identifier cashflow_date        cashflow_type   amount
0           1            a111    15/07/2023              funding  -195.71
1           2            a111    01/07/2023   interest_repayment     3.11
2           3            a111    15/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.04
3           4            a111    20/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.04
4           5            a111    11/06/2023  principal_repayment   195.33
5           6            b222    10/07/2023              funding -3915.45
6          13            b222    10/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.73
7          14            b222    10/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.73
8          15            b222    13/06/2023  principal_repayment  3906.50
```

`cashflow_date` of `funding` cashflow_type should be the earliest for each `loan_identifier`. Each row with `cashflow_type != funding` whose date is earlier than `funding` row of that `loan_identifer` should be set to `funding` cashflow_date.

So the above dataframe should look like this:

```
   identifier loan_identifier cashflow_date        cashflow_type   amount
0           1            a111    15/07/2023              funding  -195.71
1           2            a111    15/07/2023   interest_repayment     3.11
2           3            a111    15/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.04
3           4            a111    20/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.04
4           5            a111    15/07/2023  principal_repayment   195.33
5           6            b222    10/07/2023              funding -3915.45
6          13            b222    10/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.73
7          14            b222    10/07/2023   interest_repayment     0.73
8          15            b222    10/07/2023  principal_repayment  3906.50
```

Here's the data as a dictionary:

```
data = {
    'identifier': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 13, 7: 14, 8: 15},
    'loan_identifier': {0: 'a111', 1: 'a111', 2: 'a111', 3: 'a111', 4: 'a111', 5: 'b222', 6: 'b222', 7: 'b222', 8: 'b222'},
    'cashflow_date': {0: '15/07/2023', 1: '01/07/2023', 2: '15/07/2023', 3: '20/07/2023', 4: '11/06/2023', 5: '10/07/2023', 6: '10/07/2023', 7: '10/07/2023', 8: '13/06/2023'},
    'cashflow_type': {0: 'funding', 1: 'interest_repayment', 2: 'interest_repayment', 3: 'interest_repayment', 4: 'principal_repayment', 5: 'funding', 6: 'interest_repayment', 7: 'interest_repayment', 8: 'principal_repayment'},
    'amount': {0: -195.71, 1: 3.11, 2: 0.04, 3: 0.04, 4: 195.33, 5: -3915.45, 6: 0.73, 7: 0.73, 8: 3906.5}
}
```

How can I do this transformation using full advantage of pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
# ensure datetime
df['cashflow_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['cashflow_date'], dayfirst=True)
# get rows with "funding"
# NB. if more than one per ID, you need to drop duplicates
m1 = df['cashflow_type'].eq('funding')

# get reference date per ID
ref = df['loan_identifier'].map(df.loc[m1].set_index('loan_identifier')
                          ['cashflow_date'])

# change if lower than reference
m2 = df['cashflow_date'].lt(ref)
df.loc[m2, 'cashflow_date'] = ref[m2]
```

Another approach with a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['cashflow_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['cashflow_date'], dayfirst=True)

df['cashflow_date'] = (df.groupby('loan_identifier', group_keys=False)
                         .apply(lambda g: g['cashflow_date']
                                 .clip(lower=g.loc[g['cashflow_type'].eq('funding'),
                                                   'cashflow_date'].min())
                               )
                      )
```

Output:

```
   identifier loan_identifier cashflow_date        cashflow_type   amount
0           1            a111    2023-07-15              funding  -195.71
1           2            a111    2023-07-15   interest_repayment     3.11
2           3            a111    2023-07-15   interest_repayment     0.04
3           4            a111    2023-07-20   interest_repayment     0.04
4           5            a111    2023-07-15  principal_repayment   195.33
5           6            b222    2023-07-10              funding -3915.45
6          13            b222    2023-07-10   interest_repayment     0.73
7          14            b222    2023-07-10   interest_repayment     0.73
8          15            b222    2023-07-10  principal_repayment  3906.50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# converting to  datetime format
df['cashflow_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['cashflow_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

#groupby loan identifier to identify earliest cashflow date so that loan_identifier gets grouped with early date
earliest_dates = df[df['cashflow_type'] == 'funding'].groupby('loan_identifier')['cashflow_date'].min()
# a111   2023-07-15
# b222   2023-07-10

# then updating 'cashflow_date' using .loc indexer
for loan_id, earliest_date in earliest_dates.items():
    df.loc[(df['loan_identifier'] == loan_id) & (df['cashflow_type'] != 'funding') & (df['cashflow_date'] < earliest_date), 'cashflow_date'] = earliest_date

print(df)
```

Output:

```
identifier loan_identifier cashflow_date        cashflow_type   amount
0           1            a111    2023-07-15              funding  -195.71
1           2            a111    2023-07-15   interest_repayment     3.11
2           3            a111    2023-07-15   interest_repayment     0.04
3           4            a111    2023-07-20   interest_repayment     0.04
4           5            a111    2023-07-15  principal_repayment   195.33
5           6            b222    2023-07-10              funding -3915.45
6          13            b222    2023-07-10   interest_repayment     0.73
7          14            b222    2023-07-10   interest_repayment     0.73
8          15            b222    2023-07-10  principal_repayment  3906.50
```